# On-chain storage version on new chain seems to be incorrect

Tags: storage, genesis, versioning

I modified the template pallet from the substrate node template [681a9d8e3e8becf99aabf1cc76e1c08016db2e1a](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/tree/polkadot-v0.9.23) to contain a storage version:

```rust
const STORAGE_VERSION: StorageVersion = StorageVersion::new(123);

// -- snip --

#[pallet::pallet]
#[pallet::storage_version(STORAGE_VERSION)]
#[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
pub struct Pallet<T>(_);
```

Then I wrote the following test:

```rust
#[test]
fn storage_version_is_correct() {
    new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
        assert_eq!(<Pallet<Test> as GetStorageVersion>::current_storage_version(), 123);
        assert_eq!(<Pallet<Test> as GetStorageVersion>::on_chain_storage_version(), 123);
        assert_eq!(StorageVersion::get::<Pallet<Test>>(), 123);
    });
}
```

The first `assert_eq!` succeeds, the other two fail. Is this expected behavior? I would have expected the storage version of the pallet to be written to storage at genesis. If this is expected behavior, why is this the case?

I expanded `lib.rs` and found the following snippet:

```rust
impl<T: Config> frame_support::traits::OnGenesis for Pallet<T> {
    fn on_genesis() {
        let storage_version = STORAGE_VERSION;
        storage_version.put::<Self>();
    }
}
```

So it appears that the storage version is supposed to be written to the on-chain storage on genesis, right? Why didn't it happen in this case?

Comment: Can you share your repo where you have these changes? I would like to replicate your issue.

Comment: @Bruno https://github.com/maltekliemann/substrate-node-template

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following patch will make it work:

```
diff --git a/pallets/template/src/tests.rs b/pallets/template/src/tests.rs
index 550ffad..6ca03f1 100644
--- a/pallets/template/src/tests.rs
+++ b/pallets/template/src/tests.rs
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@ use frame_support::{
        assert_noop, assert_ok,
        pallet_prelude::*,
        storage::storage_prefix,
-       traits::{GetStorageVersion, StorageVersion},
+       traits::{GetStorageVersion, StorageVersion, OnGenesis},
 };
 
 #[test]
@@ -27,6 +27,7 @@ fn correct_error_for_none_value() {
 #[test]
 fn storage_version_is_correct() {
        new_test_ext().execute_with(|| {
+        Pallet::<Test>::on_genesis();
                println!(
                        "{:?}",
                        storage_prefix(<Pallet<Test>>::name().as_bytes(), b":__STORAGE_VERSION__:")
```

The problem here being that `on_genesis` is not being called magically and you don't call it in your code anywhere. `StorageVersion` defaults to `0` when it is not present in the storage.

Normally `on_genesis` being called as part of the runtime `GenesisConfig`. [Here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a9d055d55b310373b17076b9ed079a5a9b878bdb/frame/support/procedural/src/construct_runtime/expand/config.rs#L80-L82) you see the code that is being generated that will then call this method.

When you want to test migrations, I would just put the expected `StorageVersion` into the storage, before calling the migration code.

Comment: Thanks! So even when I'm using a dev node, `on_genesis` is not called?

Comment: On a dev node it is called. If you mean by dev node that you have run a node with `--dev`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. on_chain_storage_version is the version number saved in the DB.
2. And the current_storage_version's real meaning is the number which is annotated in the  pallet's pallet::storage_version macro.

Comment: Yeah, I know both of these things. Sorry to be so blunt, but this doesn't answer my question at all: "Is this expected behavior? I would have expected the storage version of the pallet to be written to storage at genesis. If this is expected behavior, why is this the case?"

Comment: "I would have expected the storage version of the pallet to be written to storage at genesis. " --- It's not work that way, storage version number in pallet::storage_version macro is just a mark, won't affect the real storage version in DB.

Comment: Okay, but why? If I start a development node after my chain has had a couple of storage migrations, this means that the development node that the incorrect storage version. This makes testing future storage migrations rather annoying. I don't see the reason for this.

Comment: Also, I've edited the question. It seems like specified storage version _does_ get put into on-chain storage at genesis.

Comment: I think your assumption is not proper. You can check this test case: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/158cdfd1a43a122f8cfbf70473fcd54a3b418f3d/frame/support/test/tests/pallet_instance.rs#L591

Comment: The test case tells us clearly, current_storage_version won't be put into storage when on_genesis.